# How do I set up mongoDB's new CSFLE feature, with explicit encryption implicit decryption using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, encryption, mongodb-csfle

I'm trying to use MongoDB's Client-Side Filed Level Encryption feature with the community edition. I'm not interested in the auto-encryption feature. However, we need the auto-decryption feature which as per the docs is possible in the community edition as well.

We generally use mongoose in our application but I tried with native nodejs driver as well. Here's the code I'm using to create the connection. This works fine if I comment out the ***autoEncryption*** object. Doing so allows me to encrypt manually, but this way we will also have to decrypt manually, which kind of beats the purpose.

Some docs suggest adding **bypassAutoEncryption: true** with **extraOptions** object to the ***autoEncryption*** object. I've treid that as well as seen below.

```js
const secureClient = new MongoClient('mongodb://someUri', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    autoEncryption: {
        keyVaultNamespace,
        kmsProviders,
        bypassAutoEncryption: true,
        extraOptions: {
            // mongocryptdBypassSpawn: true,
            mongocryptdSpawnArgs: [ "--pidfilepath=bypass-spawning-mongocryptd.pid", "--port", "27021"],
            mongocryptdURI: "mongodb://localhost:27021/db?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=1000"
        },
    }
});
```

My code is working till generating the master key, data-key and explicitly encrypting the data. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to set up the auto-decryption. To configure the client with CSFLE options the ***autoEncryption*** has to be passed in the options.
But whenever I pass this option, I get the following exception

```
(node:53721) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27021
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/NiccsJ/ORI/code/testmongoEncryption/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:325:38)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I've followed almost all suggestions from the below refs. Surprisingly, mondodb-nodejs documentation doesn't even mention **bypassAutoEncryption**. I just happen to stumble across mongodb-c(point 3 & 4 below) driver documentation where I first found ant reference of such an option

1. https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4ecaa37f72040ed8ace6eebc861b43ee9cb32a99/test/spec/client-side-encryption/tests/README.rst
2. https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8167
3. http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/client-side-encryption/
4. https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/reference/driver/crud/client_side_encryption/#explicit-encryption-and-auto-decryption

I was able to configure mongoShell with auto-decryption, meaning that my initial setup is not at fault. Also, it leads me to believe that there has to be a way to do it .via code as well.

My stack:

- nodeJS: > 14.7
- mongoDB: 4.4
- OS: macOS for dev, prod will be on AmazonLinux2
- Drivers: mongoose, native-nodejs, [mongodb-client-encryption](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-client-encryption)

It's not clearly mentioned in the docs. But from what I've read, automatic decryption doesn't require the enterprise-only mongocryptd process.

As mentioned in the official [mongoDB-c-driver](http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/client-side-encryption/)

> Although automatic encryption requires MongoDB 4.2 enterprise or a MongoDB 4.2 Atlas cluster, automatic decryption is supported for all users. To configure automatic decryption without automatic encryption, set bypass_auto_encryption=True in the options::auto_encryption class.

I believe the **bypassAutoEncryption** option was made for this very purpose.

Comment: ECONNREFUSED means the operating system actively rejected the connection because nothing is listening on that port.  Have you installed anything to listen at that `mongocryptdURI`

Comment: @Joe No, nothing is actually running on that URI. I read some [tests](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4ecaa37f72040ed8ace6eebc861b43ee9cb32a99/test/spec/client-side-encryption/tests/README.rst) that suggested some of these options have to be passed explicitly to skip the spawning of mongocryptd process. 

I don't really need those options, I just want the bypassAutoEncryption to work somehow.

Comment: If I'm reading the docs right, automatically encrypting or decrypting requires a local mongodcryptd process, which only comes with the paid enterprise version.

Comment: @Joe Actually it's a bit confusing in the docs. But mongocryptd process is only required for auto-encryption. I've made some edits to my post. Please check

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer, but this is the best resolution at the moment.
I reported this as a bug on the official JIRA.

Turns out, this apparently is a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-3605) with the node-mongo-native library.
As per their comment, this should be fixed in the next release.